# $addToSet and $inc for updating a row

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm working on a rating system. When a user rates, $inc increments the field, and `addToSet` adds the user_id to make sure the user only clicks rate once. I am checking if the user_id is already in the x field before updating, but that is another query which I'd rather avoid. Can I reach this purpose without having to write another query? I mean, `$addToSet` only adds if there is no value like that; can I instead get affected rows? Can you suggest other queries?

Thank you!

```
..->update(
    array("_id" => $idob),
    array(
       '$inc'      => array($type => (int) 1),
       '$addToSet' => array("x"   => (int) $user_id)
    )
);
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($type);` give?

Comment: I'm not sure how doing the $addtoset separate would be expensive. I think you cannot have $inc and $addtoset in one update but worth testing, I always forget these thing. Also what do you mean by "can i get affected rows"?

Comment: var dump did not give me the enough information, affected rows, is like mysql's affected rows, it is gonna give me the number of affected entries so i am going to now if it is added or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see the problem.

```
..->update(
    array("_id" => $idob),
    array(
       '$inc'      => array($type => (int) 1),
       '$addToSet' => array("x"   => (int) $user_id)
    )
);
```

The problem is that you need a conditional `$inc` there so that it only `$inc`s if it does add to set.

This is not possible with a unique index since unique indexes work from the root of the document atm. Also you probably want to use the `$inc` as a form of pre-aggregation or what not.

One method could be:

```
update(
    array('_id' => $idob, 'x' => array('$nin' => array($user_id))), 
    array(
        '$inc' => array($type => 1),
        '$push' => array('x' => (int)$user_id)
    )
)
```

This will only do the update if that user_id does not already exist in `x`.

Comment: @johna About the affected rows. You can add a "safe" => true param to the end of the update. This will give back an array with a field called "n" or "updated" which will tell you how many it updated. You can fid the safe param here wihtin the options block: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php